# How to change font color of all elements of a class through javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, dom

I have a button that changes the background image of my web app, and I want to change the color of the font when the button is clicked.

I tried making the element its own variable but that didn't work either.

```
cafeButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/cafe.jpeg')"; //change text colors
    document.getElementsByClassName('topbutton').style.color = 'blue';
})
```

When using the above code I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.

Here is a codepen of the whole project https://codepen.io/Games247/pen/XWJqebG

How do I change the text color of all elements under a class name?

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of DOM Node. So you need to loop through it and apply styles to all elements individually.

```
cafeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('img/cafe.jpeg')"; //change text colors
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('topbutton');
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.color = 'blue';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` gives you `DOMCollection`, which is nothing but array. Hence, you have to style each element inside array.
eg.

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('topbutton')].forEach((ele)=>{ele.style.color = 'blue';});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way. `document.getElementsByClassName` gives you a node list of a specific class. So you have to loop through it. So, in your code use this:

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('topbutton')
nodeList.forEach(node => {
  node.style.color = 'blue'
})
```

Or you can also use `document.querySelectorAll('.topbutton')` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('topbutton')`